# Access denied Error while passing ARN to Policy using Terraform

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

Hi i am trying to add policy for s3 Accesspoint(outpost). But while executing it i get Access Denied Error. but while i update it using Console i can update the policy.

```
resource "aws_s3_access_point" "op_access_point" {
  bucket = aws_s3control_bucket.bucket_name.arn
  name   = var.access_point_name

  vpc_configuration {
    vpc_id = var.vpc_id
  }
}

resource "aws_s3control_access_point_policy" "accesspoint_policy" {
  access_point_arn = aws_s3_access_point.access_point.arn

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [{
      Effect = "Allow"
      Action = [
        "s3-outposts:*"
      ]
      Principal = {
        AWS = "*"
      }
      Resource = [
  "${aws_s3_access_point.access_point.arn}"
      ]
    }]
  })
}
```

Output

```
Error: creating S3 Access Point (arn:aws:s3-outposts:us-west-2:404372770:outpost/op-6a30c66a/accesspoint/new_accesspoint) Policy: AccessDenied: Access Denied
│   status code: 403, request id: 7f-3672-4563-83ff-8b5ergf7, host id: sdoZ+j1yWfNSF+MvDnN08+aAMl
```

Here how do i pass the arn to policy if there is an alternate your suggestions will be helpful.

but while using policy along with Access point creation it works fine.

```
resource "aws_s3_access_point" "op_access_point" {
  bucket = aws_s3control_bucket.bucket_name.arn
  name   = var.access_point_name


 policy = jsonencode({
   Version = "2008-10-17"
   Statement = [{
     Effect = "Allow"
     Action = "s3-outposts:*"
     Principal = {
       AWS = format("arn:aws:iam::%s:root", data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id)
     }
     Resource = [format("arn:aws:s3-outposts:%s:%s:outpost/%s/accesspoint/%s", data.aws_region.current.name, data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id, var.outpost_id, var.access_point_name)]
   }]
 })

  vpc_configuration {
    vpc_id = var.vpc_id
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're misreading the error. The error is in your code for creating the access point (aws_s3_access_point.access_point) not in the policy portion. The reason it mentions a policy is because your user running terraform doesn't have the permission needed to make the resource.

Comment: updated the question with additional details. 

here i get access denied while adding policy but if  i try to add policy while creating Accesspoint it works.